# Identify all abelian groups up to Isomorphism having only one non trivial proper subgroup of finite index?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, soft-question, abelian-groups

Identify all abelian groups up to Isomorphism having only one non trivial proper subgroup of finite index?

$\exists ! H\le G$ such that $(e) \neq H<G$ and $[G:H]<\infty$

---

Finite abelian group:

Let $|G|=n$

Then $G$ satisfy the above criteria iff $n$ has only one non trivial divisor i.e $n$ has three positive divisors.

Let $n=\Pi_{i=1}^{k}p_i^{\alpha_i}$

Then $\tau(n) =\Pi_{i=1}^{k}(1+\alpha_i) =3$

Implies $n=p^2$

There are two non isomorphic abelian group of order $p^2$ i.e $Z_{p^2}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$

Since $ \mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$ isn't possible.

Hence there is only one class of abelian groups up to Isomorphism having exactly one non trivial proper subgroup with finite index i.e $G\cong Z_{p^2}$

---

Infinite abelian group:

I know two non isomorphic abelian groups having only one proper non trivial subgroup of finite index $\Bbb{Q}^*$ and $\Bbb{R}^*$.

This class may be huge, I guess.

One way may be taking the direct product of a divisible abelian group.

Is this classification possible?

Comment: If $G$ is not divisible, can you find a non-trivial torsion quotient?

Comment: What do you mean by 'proper'? The standard usage is 'nontrivial and different from $G$'. But then I do not understand the $Z_p$ example.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you professor, I have modified my question.

Comment: Your assertion about the finite case is incorrect. $C_p\times C_p$ has $p+1$ subgroups of order $p$.

Comment: Thanks, corrected.